# error[E0308]: mismatched types — expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`

Tags: rust, type-mismatch

I am making a tic-tac-toe game. The code is not complete, but I am stuck here. I want to print `array_display` to the console, but when I assign the string, an error pops-up.

```
use std::io;

fn main() {
    let mut player1: String = String::new();
    let mut player2: String = String::new();
    let mut positions = ["1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"];

    let mut lets_play = true;

    println!("Welcome to tic tac toe");
    println!("Player 1 please select what symbol you want to be : (x or o)");
    io::stdin().read_line(&mut player1);

    player1 = player1.to_lowercase();
    println!("{:?}", player1);

    if player1.trim() == "x" {
        player1 = String::from("x");
        player2 = String::from("o");
        println!("Player 1 is x");
    } else if player1.trim() == "o" {
        player1 = String::from("o");
        player2 = String::from("x");
        println!("Player 1 is o");
    } else {
        println!("Input is not valid");
        lets_play = false;
    }
    if lets_play {
        println!("Let's start the game :");

        print_board(&mut positions);
    } else {
        println!("Please reset the game");
    }
}

fn print_board(arr: &mut [&str]) {
    let mut counter = 0;
    let mut array_display = ["1", "2", "3"];
    let mut array_position = 0;
    let mut string_for_array = String::new();

    for i in 0..arr.len() {
        string_for_array.push_str(arr[i]);
        counter += 1;
        if counter == 3 {
            println!(
                "array_display[{}] value =  {}",
                array_position, string_for_array
            );
            array_display[array_position] = string_for_array.to_string();
            println!("String to push {:?}", string_for_array);
            string_for_array = String::from("");
            println!("Array position {}", array_position);
            array_position += 1;
            counter = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Error:

```
error[E0308]: mismatched types
  --> src/main.rs:52:45
   |
52 |             array_display[array_position] = string_for_array.to_string();
   |                                             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |                                             |
   |                                             expected `&str`, found struct `std::string::String`
   |                                             help: consider borrowing here: `&string_for_array.to_string()`
```

Comment: *help: consider borrowing here: `&string_for_array.to_string()`* — what happened when you tried this?

Comment: You might see it better if you execute it but I get error[E0716]: temporary value dropped while borrowed ,array_display[array_position] = borrow later used here ,&string_for_array.to_string(); = creates a temporary which is freed while still in use

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The current issue in your code is that `string_for_array.to_string()` creates a new `String`, but the `array_display` array contains `&str` references.

The suggestion the compiler gives here (replacing with `&string_for_array.to_string()`) does not work, because the result of `.to_string()` will be freed at the end of the line and you would have an invalid `&str` reference.

So, the issue is: some variable needs to own that string. Since `string_for_array` is modified later, it can't be used. The natural choice is `array_display` (because that's where that string will live anyway). So, first modify this array to contain owned `String`s instead of `&str` references:

```rust
    let mut array_display = ["1".to_owned(), "2".to_owned(), "3".to_owned()];
```

And then the rest of the code will compile.

Comment: This worked, still new to rust, still finding it hard to understand the borrowing , reference stuff,I did not know about the to_owned() , I have also seen .clone(),etc.

I will investigate more, thanks!